# Resolving classes in Laravel leads to PhpStorm "Cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am resolving a class in Laravel 10 like the following:

```php
$myService = resolve(MyService::class);
$myService->methodOnMyServiceClass();
```

However, in PhpStorm, I cannot click through to the method, and it says:

> "Cannot find declaration to go to"

Is this something to do with the Laravel `resolve()` method that my IDE is not recognising? It's frustrating because the function name is now greyed out like it's not being used.

I'm having to use `resolve()` because I was previously writing `$myService = new MyService()`, but my dependency injection was not working without me resolving the class.

Any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: 1) What PhpStorm says about `$myService` variable on that 2nd line? What type it thinks it is? Place a caret on it and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (`Ctrl+Q` here on Windows keymap). 2) Do you use Laravel IDE Helper package? (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Comment: You have to install `composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` and then run `php artisan ide:meta`, you can also run `php artisan ide:gen`. That package will generare a meta file that is only readable by PHPStorm, and will help you woth exactly your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a doc line by specifying the type of a variable. This will help the IDE understand it's class

```
/** @var MyService $myService */
$myService = resolve(MyService::class);
$myService->methodOnMyServiceClass();
```